# How do I create a non-blocking system call in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to make a `system` call in ruby, but rather than wait for the process to terminate, I want my script to continue running.

What's the recommended way to handle this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Process.spawn`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Process.html#M001282).

Once the process is spawned, you can either wait for the process to terminate (using `waitpid`) or `detach` it.

Comment: +1 `Process#spawn` gives finer control for setting up the child process than does `IO#popen`.

Answer (score 4):

See [`IO#popen`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000880) in the standard library.

```
f = IO.popen("date")
f.gets # => "Wed Aug 10 14:56:59 MDT 2011\n"
f.close
```

Comment: Anything I should worry about if I'm going to let my ruby process end before the subprocess finishes? I assume my subprocess should continue to run and get cleaned up without explicitly calling `f.close`?

Comment: Hmm, I suppose it depends on what the child process is doing but as long as you don't need any interactions between the parent and child processes then it should be fine (e.g. no need to call "`f.close`").